# Vuejs <router-link> same route but different parameter

Tags: vue.js

I have the component: same route but different parameter

```
<router-link :to="{name: 'menu1-mostrar', params: {atr: var1}}"> 
     Menu1
</router-link>

<router-link :to="{name: 'menu1-mostrar', params: {atr: var2}}">
     Menu2
</router-link>
```

I'm not getting the component to update automatically. I can only update by clicking on another menu item that has the different route.

Note that `menu 1` and `menu 2` use the same route. When I click `menu 1` and then if I want to click `menu 2` it does not call the route again. I have to call for example `menu 3` that uses different route and then `menu 2` I need the route always be called independent if I am already in it.

Comment: can you share any live example or live snippet ?

Answer (score 2):

Because the route is the same, the component does not have to be changed, from a vue-router point of view.

Your component must be reactive to the parameter: Change your component values when the parameter change.

Solution 1: Watch for your parameter change, inside the component.

```
watch:{
   atr(newValue, oldValue){
      //handle change, maybe refresh 
   }
}
```

Solution 2: Use your parameter inside computed values:

```
computed:{
   myBusinessValue(){
      return this.atr + " is the value of the param atr!!!"
   }
}
```

Depending of what happend when the parameter change, you will use sol1 or sol2. You can give more details about that to guide you on one or the other.

Comment: Just wanted to share that this doesn't actually works, neither `watch` or `computed` in this case will give you a different `atr` value.

Answer (score 2):

You need to watch the attribute through the $route object, like so:

```
  watch: {
    '$route.params.atr': {
      handler () {
        // Do stuff
      }
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to watch the route, just use the fullpath as key on your router view.

See this response on another thread, worked for me !